# Group's subsidiary of group subsidiary

Tags: grammaticality

Please clarify should I write group's subsidiary or group subsidiary? what is the correct way to write this? Could you please also clarify the rule?

I see, there are a lot of similar situations, for example, management representation or management's representation, management report or management's report

Answer (score 0):

According to section 7.25 ("Possessive versus attributive forms") in *The Chicago Manual of Style*, they argue that the *CMoS* "dispenses with the apostrophe **only** in proper names (often corporate names) that do not use one or where there is clearly no possessive meaning."

In your example, there is the clear indication of possession. Therefore, I would lean towards "group's subsidiary".

Whether this is practised differently in British English, I cannot yet say. I didn't immediately find anything to suggest that is the case.

Comment: Marinus, thanks a lot! Can someone else give some comments?